# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user' почему не работает?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot

Пишу в чате к примеру не в ответ `!обнять` , оно выдаёт это:

```
File "visages.py", line 11, in handle_text_messages
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} \nобнял \n{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'from_user'
```

Что нужно делать? :( Я только учусь делать.

Вот код бота

```
import time
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('') #скрыл

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text_messages(message):


    if message.text == "!обнять":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} \nобнял \n{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}")
    elif message.text == "!шалун":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "--------------------- \nШалун 1.0 Custom\n--------------------- \nЭто неофициальная версия шалуна, но с вырезанной автобана, рекламмы и т.д. \nНу удачно провести ночь  \nКоманды бота - !команды")
    elif message.text == "!поцеловать":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} \nпоцеловал(а) в губки \n{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name}")
    elif message.text == "!помацать":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{message.from_user.first_name} \nчмокнул(а) в губки \n{message.reply_to_message.from_user.first_name} �")
    elif message.text == "/commands@Shalyni4kabot":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Команды данного бота... \n------------------------------ \nНу думаю описывать не надо. \n1.!шалун (инфо о боте) \n2.!поцеловать \n3.!обнять \n4.!помацать \n5.шлёп \n6.!вдуть \n7.!куни \n8.!минет \n9.!чмок \n------------------------------ \nНа заметку: Эти команды нужно нужно писать в ответ. И + чтобы всё гладко работало нужны права администратора...")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Получается, что ваш message == None и не имеет атрибутов по типу .from_user

Comment: dhvcc, а как сделать исключение?

Comment: В плане? Можете обернуть в try: ... except: ..., если я вас правильно понял

Comment: @dhvcc ну так что-бы эта ошибка пропала...

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(regexp=r'.*(?:с|С|c|C)(?:п|g)(?:а|о|f)(?:сиб|cb,)(?:jxrb|очки|о|а|j)|'
                            r'(?:б|Б)лагодар(?:ю|им|очка)|(?:п|П)(?:а|о)си(?:б|п).*')
def regex_thanks(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'supergroup' and message.from_user.id not in users:
        thanks = ['пожалуйста', 'не за что', 'всегда рады помочь', 'не стоит благодарности', 'было приятно Вам помочь',
                  'мне за это деньги платят', 'а как мы то рады Вам помочь, не пересказать',
                  'спасибо, что хоть чем-то озадачили', 'обращайтесь', '', 'пустяк', 'без проблем']
        bot.reply_to(message, ' ' + random.choice(thanks))
```